# In Laravel Eloquent how to define relationship through secondary table? (Always returning 0 relations)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I feel like this should work. I have a list of products and categories (types).

Tables:

```
Products
    - id
    - name
    - etc
Types
    - id
    - name
    - etc
ProductTypes
    - product_id
    - type_id
```

Now, I feel like in the `Type` model in Laravel, I should be able to define this relationship:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Product::class, ProductType::class, 'type_id', 'id');
}
```

I've tried other variations with the secondary ids in the additional parameters but no luck, always an empty list. Is `ProductTypes` a pivot table and therefore should be dealt with differently?

Edit: What's weird is that for the final 2 parameters (`$localKey = null, $secondLocalKey = null`) even if I enter complete garbage no error is thrown but these 2 parameters `$firstKey = null, $secondKey = null` have to be correct).

Comment: use belongsToMany in both ways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong relationship. Based on your database structure, a product can belong to many type. Therefore, it should be a `BelongsToMany` instead of a `HasManyThrough`.

You can achieve what you want with the following method, by passing the table name of your `ProductTypes` as the second parameter:

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_types');
}
```

If your `ProductType` model extends `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot`, you can do:

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_types')
        ->using(ProductType::class);
}
```

For more information about Many to Many relationships: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many